# Eclipse auto-complete of filenames

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, plugins, filenames

Does anyone know if there exists a plugin to Eclipse which can auto complete filenames for files in the project.

So if I type images/s [Alt+tab] it should present a list of all files located in images starting with s. Like the auto-complete for types but using filenames.

It would be really cool if it worked with all kinds of editors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

Ctrl Shift R to open any other resource in the project, e.g. *.jpg

---

Martin, in response to your comment, in those cases I usually use the find command which is available in Linux and Windows/cygwin

`find . -name '*.jpg'`

Comment: I do not want to open the resource in eclipse. I want to insert the name of the file as text. Imagine I am writing html and can't remember all the names of the different images when doing an img tag

Comment: Cntrl Shift R is great - you can use wildcards as armandino says, but you can also find a file easily if you know its name.  E.G.  If you need to open the class named MyObjectFactory.java, you can type Cntrl Shift R and type 'MOF' in the box, and it'll use the mixed case to list all files that have capital M O and F in their names.